# Regex force group order

Tags: regex

I'm new in regex and I have a question.
Like in this example, https://regex101.com/r/Iak7cF/1/ how do I force

```
src="wow"
```

to be in group 1, and

```
title="toto"
```

to be in group 2?

I want to capture this kind of text in any order only if it contains:

```
class="formula"
```

Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You'd better use an HTML parser**

But if you really want to use regex, you have to use named groups to achieve what you want.

```
<img(?=[^>]*class="formula")(?=.*(?<src>src=".*"))(?=.*(?<title>title=".*")).*>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nMK0e1/1)

Comment: No need to use named groups with this regex    <img(?=[^>]*class="formula")(?=.*(src=".*"))(?=.*(title=".*")).*> src will be in group 1 and title in group 2

Comment: @Plomging: Yes, you're right, but it's clearer when you use the named groups.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are very flexible and powerful, but in general, they are not the right tool for parsing XML, HTML, or XHTML. From [WinBatch](http://techsupt.winbatch.com/webcgi/webbatch.exe?techsupt/nftechsupt.web%20WinBatch/XML%20Parsing~XML~with~Regular~Expressions.txt):

> Regular Expressions are only good for parsing text that is tightly defined. Since Regular Expressions don't really understand the context of matches, they can be fooled in a big way if the structure of the text changes. In particular, Regular Expressions have difficulty with hierarchy.

PerlMonks has [a detailed explanation](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1201438;showspoiler=1201438-1) of why regex is not a good solution for all but the most simple of casess. They summarize it like this:

> So I hope it is clear: Please, don't try to parse arbitrary XML/HTML with regexes!